# controlling number of concurrent connection apache server

Tags: apache, shell, cpu-usage

I'm using apache with ldirector i'm facing some issues during load times when google, bing crawlers hit my site it makes apache to choke due to which my server's cup useage went to 100% utlization. after this i have to stop apache and monitor load manually i want to automate all this scenario. here is what i want when ever load comes on apache it normalizes server according to given settings and if cpu usage goes high it should not be exceded to given cpu usage limit.

I want to control all this via shell script, please give suggestions.

Comment: You can not do this using shell scripting alone.  You want a load balancer to sit in front of your servers.

Comment: Thanks charles for your comment, i'm already using load balancer in front of webservers, problem is when crawlers came to server they choke all webservers. cpu utlization went too much high due to which apache stops responding. then i manually restart apache.

Comment: I have found a tool that helps me to ban ips which keeps too many connections on server. Fail2Ban helps me out alot. It have many other functionality like Ddos and brute force. You can customize it according to your needs.